# Usage of aggregate function Group by

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I have observed that Count function can be used without the usage of aggregate function Group by. Like for example:

```
Select Count(*) from  Employee
```

It would surely return the count of all the rows without the usage of aggregate function. Then where do we really need the usage of group by?

Comment: So how would you query looked if you would like to have a count of directors, managers and workers?

Comment: `GROUP BY` is used for a lot of queries. In your example, say you wanted to find the number of employees in each department.  You would add `GROUP BY dept` to your query above, and that would return a count of all unique dept numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omitting the `GROUP BY` implies that the entire table is one group.  Sometimes you want there to be multiple groups.  Consider the following example:

```
SELECT month, SUM(sales) AS total_sales
FROM all_sales
GROUP BY month;
```

This query gives you a month-by-month breakdown of sales.  If you omitted `month` and the `GROUP BY` clause, you would only receive the total sales of all time which may not have the granularity you require.

You can also group by multiple columns, giving finer detail still:

```
SELECT state, city, COUNT(*) AS population
FROM all_people
GROUP BY state, city;
```

Additionally, using a `GROUP BY` allows us to use [`HAVING`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clauses.  Which lets us filter groups.  Using the above example, we can filter the result to cities with over 1,000,000 people:

```
SELECT state, city, COUNT(*) AS population
FROM all_people
GROUP BY state, city
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1000000;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `group by` clause is used to break up aggregate results to groups of unique values. E.g., let's say you don't want to know how many employees you have, but how many by each first name (e.g., two Gregs, one Adam and three Scotts):

```
SELECT   first_name, COUNT(*)
FROM     employee
GROUP BY first_name
```